# What happens when I interact with objects in the scene while still in Edit Mode for another?

Tags: edit-mode

I often find myself “stuck” in Edit Mode for one object while I’m trying to interact with other objects, change their materials, add modifiers, etc.  I’ll eventually realize I forgot to exit Edit Mode and that’s why everything is behaving strangely.

What exactly is different while I’m still in Edit Mode for an object? Sometimes my changes seem to just not stick. Sometimes only certain changes I make have any effect.

Comment: "Sometimes only certain changes I make have any effect", could you please be more specific?

Comment: Editing geometry nodes continues to work as normal for example, but adding new modifiers only applies to the object being edited, regardless of which other objects you've tried selecting.

Answer (score 1):

You should not interact with other objects when you are in Edit mode. There are a few exceptions, for example you can select another object from edit mode and that is helpful in some circumstances, but generally you are meant to go into edit mode, edit the object, then go out of edit mode to work with other objects. Edit mode is for editing an object, object mode is for working with objects. This is how Blender is designed and switching in and out of edit mode is not optional for many operations in Blender.

Going in and out of edit mode is just something you will definitely have to learn if you want to be able to use Blender effectively.

Comment: Right I get that. I'm just trying to understand what exactly is happening in this case.

After further experimenting, I think the answer is that my selecting other objects in Edit Mode isn't actually making them active the way it does in Object Mode (the Properties Editor still reflects the original object, for example), and so further actions like adding a modifier are actually being made to the object I'm editing, not the one I tried selecting.

Comment: Edited object remains active object, but not only that, everything in Blender is designed to work this way - there are different functions available in different modes. You simply cannot do same things from different modes. The whole idea is that you do different things in different modes. This is sort of core principle in Blender, this is how it's designed and intended to be. The program is switched to different mode of operation - that's what is happening.